# Can't understand classpath for the life of me

Tags: java, classpath, javac

Please explain classpath to me like I'm 10 yo.

When I compile a program with javac, I usually go to the root folder where the main class is:

```
javac Test.java
```

it compiles the program and all the classes in sub directories. for the above example:

`C:\newApp\`  ---> this is the folder where main class (Test.java) is located.

`C:\newApp\com\example\class`   ---> this is the folder where some other classes are there.

javac compiles all java files with that single command. makes .class file for them.

now I can just run the app with :

```
java Test
```

What is classpath? What exactly is classpath in this case?? What should I know about classpath?? When using an IDE, do I need to set it??

Comment: when using and IDE (like Eclipse or IntelliJ) you don't need to know about classpath, bcause it's done automatically.

Comment: @vvvsg I'm using Eclipse and the classpath ALWAYS fucks me over hard. I can't run ANYTHING. Always get the error "No Main Type"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's assume that your command prompt's current directory is `C:\newApp` and a class called `Test` lives in `C:\newApp\Test.java`.

The classpath is simply the location, or set of locations where class files can be found, that your program might need to use. The classpath includes folders, JARs, and (in certain more complex setups) other sources of classfiles.

When Java needs to load a class, it looks on the classpath for it. The default classpath is the set of Jars that contain Java's built-in classes, combined with the current directory of your shell prompt (`C:\newApp` in this case).

When you try to load a class, say `com.example.MyClass`, Java will look in your classpath, in the location `C:\newApp\com\example\MyClass.class`. You can tell it to get the class from a JAR (which is nothing more than a ZIP archive with a .jar file extension) by putting said JAR on the classpath. It'll look inside the jar and "unzip" classes from there as needed.

When using an IDE, you do not generally need to worry about the classpath. The IDE will automatically put *your* code in the classpath automatically when running. If you want to use code from an external library, you simply need to tell your IDE to add it to the project (usually by putting it into your project folder and right-clicking it in the file list). It will then know that its autocomplete functionality should include available classes from that Jar, *and* that the Jar is to be placed on the classpath when running your project.

Answer (score 3):

A [class-path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) is usually a list of paths where the process looks for resources (can be classes, executables, XML files or anything else). When you're using an IDE such as Eclipse the classpath is usually set for you as long as you include everything the the IDE itself (for example: add external jars interaction).

From oracle:

> The class path is the path that the Java runtime environment searches for classes and other resource files. The class search path (more commonly known by the shorter name, "class path") can be set using either the -classpath option when calling a JDK tool (the preferred method) or by setting the CLASSPATH environment variable. The -classpath option is preferred because you can set it individually for each application without affecting other applications and without other applications modifying its value.

This is an example from the link of setting multiple folders in the class-path to find class files in the directory `C:\java\MyClasses` as well as classes in `C:\java\OtherClasses`:

```
C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses ...
```